# How To Setup A Converter To Return Properties From Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, viewmodel, templatebinding

I'm making a style for a custom control that will can be one of two colors.

My properties of my control are: { SolidColorBrush color1, SolidColorBrush color2, bool usingColor1}.

I'm trying to make a converter that will bind to usingColor1 and will return either color1 or color2. I would like to define my converter like this:

```
<Style.Resources>
      <Converters:ValueParameterComparisonConverter x:Key="Color1WhenTrue" ValueWhenEqual="{DataTemplateKey Color1}" ValueWhenNotEqual="{DataTemplateKey Color2}"/>
</Style.Resources>
```

And use my converter like this:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding UsingColor1, Converter={StaticResource Color1WhenTrue}}" />
```

I have implemented this in my code and it does not work. I do not understand what DataTemplateKey does and do not think it is the correct word for this scenario.

How can I setup my converter to return properties from my template?

**Edit:**

Here is the interesting part of the converter code:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      bool isEqual;
      if (value == null)
      {
        isEqual = null == parameter;
      }
      else
      {
        isEqual = value.Equals(parameter);
      }

      return isEqual ? this.ValueWhenEqual : this.ValueWhenNotEqual;
}
```

Comment: Could you show your converter class too please?

Comment: I posted the convert() function

Comment: In your converter return `ValueWhenEqual` or `ValueWhenNotEqual` if that is the property holding colour.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the valueWhenEqual parameters;

```
<Style.Resources>
      <Converters:ValueParameterComparisonConverter x:Key="Color1WhenTrue"/>
</Style.Resources>
```

Just use a binding rather than a templatebinding;

```
<Border Background="{Binding UsingColor1, Converter={StaticResource Color1WhenTrue}}" />
```

Then change your converter to return the color you want when true and another color when false;

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  var usingColor1 = (bool)value;

  return usingColor1 ? new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(179, 255, 179)) : new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 100, 0));
}
```

Obviously you'll need to change the colors used in the example I've given.